# Bootstrap Calendar Glyphicons not showing properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, glyphicons

I have Bootstrap form which has calendar icon into form-group as like in following image.
[image]

I have problem when only add calendar icon into it all other icon works fine.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
```

Comment: Try to include some additional information please. Maybe the output of the console if you see any errors there. The offending piece of code. Anything really to help us identify the problem at hand.

Comment: Check if `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` is loading properly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if the font directory is correctly installed.

Should be located in your_project_folder/bootstrap/fonts/

Also, make sure you wrote correctly:

All available glyphicons are listed here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: I am using asp.net according its hierarchy its in content folder. other icon works fine but it can't load calendar icon somehow :(

I am using bootstrap v3.3.4

Comment: Okay. Include some additional info or code, please :) Check also which encode is set.

Comment: This is how i add calendar icon into it. <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Also I am using bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.

When you'll see the [`boostrap.css`](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css), you can see that:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Thus, when you're putting your css file offline, it'll look for the font files locally, which it won't be able to find. Thus all you need to do is to create a folder named `fonts`, that is one level up from the `css` file.

That is

```
|
|
-css---bootstrap.css
|
-fonts ---glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        |
        |
        --glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

My glyph started working after downloading these two files only. You might need to download more.

The links to these files:

- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

If you require any more similar files, just change the file names, you'll get them.